# What am I doing wrong with array_walk (and is there a better way)?

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

I have an array called "methods" and it looks like so:

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => WWAM
    [title] => WWAM
    [cost] => 4.35
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => CNQM
    [title] => CNQM
    [cost] => 5.21
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => CNAM
    [title] => CNAM
    [cost] => 6.58
    )
```

What I want to do is alter each [cost] such that it is [cost] minus (min)[cost].  In other words, each one below would be reduced by 4.35 (the WWAM one would then be zero).  There's probably a better way to go about this, but I figured I'd try array_walk.  It isn't working out for me though.  Here's what I tried:

```
      $lowestpricedoption = 100000;
      foreach ($methods as $item) {
        if ($item['cost'] < $lowestpricedoption) {
          $lowestpricedoption = $item['cost'];
        }
      }
      array_walk( $methods, 'subtractLowest', $lowestpricedoption );

      function subtractLowest(&$item, $key, $lowestval)
      {
        $item['cost'] -= $lowestval;
      }
```

I partly want to know why that isn't working, but I also would appreciate a more elegant method.

Comment: It works. Recheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uasort()` function of PHP that'll sort your array as per your `cost` value within `ascending` order. And then simply use the `current()` function along with the array dereferencing and you'll get the lowest value of cost

```
uasort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return $a['cost'] - $b['cost'];
});
$min = current($arr)['cost'];
array_walk($arr,function(&$v,$k)use($min){
    $v['cost'] -= $min;
});
print_r($arr);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/459058)

Comment: Wow!  That introduces a lot of new concepts for me.  I've got some reading to do.  But one thing that I'm going to have a heck of a time with Google on... what is "$result = []" doing?

Comment: Tried it and it certainly did the job!  I don't understand it (yet), but thank you!

Comment: That's just of no use over here.